# Select n random groups of n rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table `services`, with data as follows:

```
service_id  bepro_id    service_name
        1   1   Virtuales
        2   2   Logos1
        3   3   Diseño C
        4   1   Formatos A3
        203 77  Dasdad
        6   2   Publi
        8   4   edificios Vi
        9   3   Maquillaje D
        10  7   Servicio 10 Serv
        11  4   servicio 11 tittle
        14  3   Lorem ipsum dol
        15  30  servicio 15 title
        16  4   Titulo TituloTitulo
        17  8   servicio 17 title Ã±
        19  11  Retoques digital 
        20  4   servicio 20 title
        26  5   service 26 title
        27  7   servicio 27 tittle
        183 3   Excepteur sint occaecat 
        188 3    Duis aute irure dolor 
        185 3   Cillum dolore eu fugiat
        186 3   Eserunt mollit anim i
        190 3   Lorem ipsum dolor
        191 3   general para ed
        192 3   Ingenieria
        193 3   letras
        194 2   bocetos
        196 60  Retoque fotografico
        199 60  Maquetacion de 
        198 28  Revistas en General
```

I want to select from 8 distinct random values in `bepro_id` 1 to 8 per each values (minimun 1 ,maximun 8) each `bepro_id`.

I mean maximum 64 rows or minimum 8 rows. Then I have to JOIN with table "users" where services.bepro_id=users.users_id .

This selects only one random row per value ( I need min 1 max 8 values for each value) below @Andomar help me a lot but doesn't seems to work and it look complicated for what it is , is that the only way i could do?:

```
SELECT * FROM  `services` GROUP BY bepro_id ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 8
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the MySQL variable trick to label each row with a row number.  An `inner join` can be used to limit the result to N bepro's.  The example below returns 1-2 random services for 3 random bepro's.  It should be easy to change those values.

This is what i need thank to @Andomar :

```
select  *
from    (
        select  distinct bepro_id
        from    services
        order by
                rand()
        limit   8 -- Eight random bepro_id's
        ) bepro
join    (
        select  if(@last_bepro = bepro_id, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn
        ,       (@last_bepro := bepro_id)
        ,       service_id
        ,       bepro_id
        ,       service_name
        from    services
        cross join
                (select @rn := 0, @last_bepro := -1) r
        order by
                bepro_id
        ) serv
on      serv.bepro_id = bepro.bepro_id
join    users 
on      users.id = bepro.bepro.id
where   serv.rn <= 8 -- 8 services max , 1 min per bepro_id
order by
        rand();
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ad25/2/0)

Comment: Right now the query returns 1-8 services.  If you want 8 services always, replace `floor(1 + (rand() * 2))` with `8`.  You can add another join just before the `where` clause.

Comment: It's random after all.  It'd have to pick a bepro with 8+ services and then roll 8 on the 1-8 to return all 8.  If you always want 8, replace "floor(1 + (rand() * 2))" with "8" (removing the floor and rand entirely)

Comment: Then replace `floor(1 + (rand() * 2))` with `8`, like I have suggested twice in comments above ;)

Comment: If you remove `order by bepro.bepro_id;` from the end, the rows should appear in random order.